# Error while importing JQuery library net::ERR_Aborted 404

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, apache, ecmascript-6

Working on a Java project in eclipse ide. I downloaded and added jQuery library in my Web/module_name/WebContent/js folder. In my code I have imported the file as:

```html
<script src="/module_name/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

When I run the server, I am getting error as net::ERR_Aborted 404 and the address in the error line is showing as:

GET http://localhost:8080/module_name/js/jquery-1.12.4.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: using `./` instead of `/` may fix it.

Comment: @Cyruskabir <script src="./module_name/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> is this correct ? (tried this but it didn't work)

Comment: yes it's correct.